# lambda expression as non-type template argument

Tags: c++, c++17

`clang -std=c++1z` accepts

```
void foo();

template <auto f>
struct F {};

int main()
{
   F<+[](){foo();}> f;
}
```

Note the `+` to force the conversion to function pointer.

But gcc 7.1 rejects it `error: lambda-expression in template-argument`.
Which one is right?

Comment: The rocket's right, the conversion does not matter.

Comment: Thanks.
https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=33696