# Can a lambda appear in template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++17

Here's a small snippet of code:

```
template<void(*)()> struct s{};

int main() {
    s<+[]{}> t;
}
```

I'm trying to take the pointer to the function of the lambda. It compiles in clang but GCC rejects it:

> main.cpp:5:8: error: lambda-expression in template-argument
>
> ```
>   s<+[]{}> t;
>     ^
> ```
>
> main.cpp:5:12: error: template argument 1 is invalid
>
> ```
>   s<+[]{}> t;
>          ^
> ```

The following code compiles with both GCC and clang:

```
template<void(*)()> struct s{};

constexpr auto f = +[]{};
int main() {
    s<f> t;
}
```

Which compiler is right and why?

Comment: Here's a perfect dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44931130/lambda-expression-as-non-type-template-argument?noredirect=1&lq=1